# Get last 4 digits of card Stripe Checkout

Tags: stripe-payments

I am using Stripe Checkout to process orders on my site and then save the order once its complete using the webhook `Checkout.Session.Complete` . It works all well and good but I would like to store the last 4 digits used to process the order. If I send a receipt using Stripe it lists that info so I know its possible, I just prefer to store it and send my own receipt to customize and assist customers if an order is off. The [checkout session object](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/object) doesnt list the last 4 digits for some reason so whats the best way to get that info based on what the [session object](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/object) returns???

Answer (score 4):

The answer will depend on the type of Checkout Session you are working with.

If you are working with Checkout Sessions where `mode:payment`, then you should expand `payment_intent.payment_method` when you retrieve the Session. Then, you can check `payment_intent.payment_method.card.last4` to get the last 4 digits.

If you are working with Checkout Sessions where `mode:subscription`, then you should expand `subscription.default_payment_method` when you retrieve the Session. Then, you can check `subscription.default_payment_method.card.last4`.

If you're not already familiar with expansion, you can read more about it here (https://stripe.com/docs/expand).

Comment: How do you add `expand` on webhooks?

Comment: @cglacet - You can't add expand to webhooks. You'll need to re-retrieve the object if you need to use expand

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem.
Expanding @karbi answer i could get the last four digits of the credit card as following:

```
  public async subscriptionCreated(payload: any, signature: string) {
    try {
      const customerId = payload.data.object.customer;
      const checkoutId = payload.data.object.id;

      const session = await this.stripe.checkout.sessions.retrieve(
        checkoutId,
        {
          expand: ['subscription.default_payment_method'],
        }
      );
      //@ts-ignore
     // For some reason that i don't know it just says that the property does not exist but it's not true.
     const lastFour = session.subscription.default_payment_method.card.last4;
    
     // Rest of your code!
}
```

I am using NestJs. So my controller looks like this.

```
  @Public()
  @Post('/webhooks/success')
  public async subscriptionCreated(
    @Body() payload: any,
    @Headers('stripe-signature') signature: string,
  ) {

    if (!signature) {
      throw new BadRequestException('Invalid signature');
    }

    await this.service.subscriptionCreated(payload);
    return 'received';
  }
```

I hope to help someone else who is struggling with this in the future.